# How do i remove a number that is at the end of each line in a text file?

Tags: text, txt, editing

So i have a huge text file of about 3800 lines. This text file got the following format
"By Name,number" What i want to do is remove this number at the end from all those lines

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Are you using a programming language or just a text editor ? Also, can you give an example (*a few rows of  your file*) and show the exacted matching expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the text file using 'VS code'(visual studio code) or 'atom' here you have functionality to add multiple cursors by holding the alt key (on windows) and then left clicking the places where u want to change something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).